# Button Click Event - Lotus Script

Tags: lotusscript

I want proper lotus script for button click event that on click pops out a keyword list of staff to select and place on the superior1 field... I am not sure of the parameters to be given... please help me with that... I followed the below script and it didnt work... it is showin an empty dialog list...:(... or else provide me an alternative formula or sumthin to work this out... thx a lot...

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)
    Dim session As New notessession
    Dim view,view1 As NotesView 
    Dim doc,doc1 As notesdocument
    Dim db As Notesdatabase
    Set db=session.CurrentDatabase 

    Dim Overdb As notesdatabase

    Set Overdb=session.GetDatabase(db.server, "Master\\ASEAN_Staff.nsf")

    Dim workspace As New NotesUIWorkspace
    Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument
    Dim picklist As Variant
    Set uidoc = workspace.CurrentDocument

    If Superior1= "" Then

        Sup1$ = uidoc.FieldGetText("Superior1")

        picklist = workspace.PickListStrings( PICKLIST_CUSTOM,_
        False,_
        db.server,_
        "Master\\ASEAN_Staff.nsf",_
        "x_asean_search",_
        "Select Name",_
        4,_
        Sup1$ ) 


    End If

End Sub
```

Thx a lot Hristo & mbonaci...:) I've wrked out with the pickliststrings and i've got wat i wanted i.e to display a list of superior1 keywords categorized by group column... foll is the script tat i used ...

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)
Dim session As New notessession
Dim view As NotesView 
Dim view1  As notesview
Dim doc,doc1 As notesdocument
Dim db As Notesdatabase
Set db=session.CurrentDatabase 

Dim Overdb As notesdatabase

Set Overdb=session.GetDatabase(gsserver, gspath + "Master\\ASEAN_Staff.nsf")

Dim workspace As New NotesUIWorkspace
Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument
Dim picklist As Variant
Set uidoc = workspace.CurrentDocument

If Superior1= "" Then

    'Sup1 = uidoc.FieldGetText("Superior1")

    'Ofc = uidoc.FieldGetText("Office")
    Gp = uidoc.FieldGetText("Group")
    'og = doc.Office + doc.Group


    picklist = workspace.PickListStrings( PICKLIST_CUSTOM,_
    False,_
    gsserver,_
    "Master\\ASEAN_Staff.nsf",_
    "x_asean_search",_
    "Select Name",_
    "Choose",_
    1,_
    Gp ) 



End If

End Sub
```

Now, on selectin any keyword from the list... for eg: "Executive" shud be placed on the field "Superior1" of the current document/form... wazz the script for this... plz help me...

Answer (score 1):

As written, the `PickListStrings` should result in an error, because there is a missing argument on the seventh position - the `prompt$` ([help for PickListStrings](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_PICKLISTSTRINGS_METHOD_4229_ABOUT.html)) and Notes does not expect a number (4 in this case) as an argument.

Other than that:

- Have you tried opening the target view ("x_asean_search" in "Master\ASEAN_Staff.nsf") and typing the string from field `Superior1` (the value you test with) to make sure there is such category? The focus should move to that category, if it exists in the view.
- Try printing the `Sup1$` in the status bar to make sure it contains the expected value.
- Is the fourth column of the view the one, which values you want to return?

Not causing a problem, but good to keep in mind:

- `Dim view,view1 As NotesView` declares variable `view` of type `Variant` and `view1` of type `NotesView`. Put them on separate lines to avoid the possibility of unexpected behavior. For example, here a statement `If (view is Nothing) Then` will result in a "Type Mismatch" error.
- The variable `Superior1` from `If Superior1= "" Then` seems to be a variant with value EMPTY, so the condition is always true. Using `Option Declare` is a good practice that would prevent this from compiling.

Comment: @mbonaci is right to suggest using a formula as a much more concise solution. My understanding, though is that @SarahXP wants to limit the choices from the target view to those, under a category that corresponds to the value in field "Superior1" of the currently opened document. In this case, she should use @DbLookup instead, for example: `@DbLookup( "ReCache"; @Subset(@DbName; 1) : "Master\\ASEAN_Staff.nsf"; "x_asean_search"; Superior1; 4)` and use the result list in a dialog.

Comment: @SarahXP - Also, if you chose to stick to LotusScript, try removing one backslash from "Master\\ASEAN_Staff.nsf" - I think you only need one.

Comment: Well... I've got the solution for getting the selected keyword to the field "Superior1"... can anyone help me with this... I wanna compare a combination of 2 fields "Office" & "Fields" with a column "OfficeGroup" of the view...for eg: Field A value & Field B value with Column "AB"... hw do i concatenate both the fields..? I prefer LOTUS SCRIPT instead of formula for this plz... thx...

Comment: To concatenate the values of two items in a document using LotusScript (assuming each field contains a single value) use `notesDoc.GetItemValue("fieldA")(0) + notesDoc.GetItemValue("fieldB")(0)`

Comment: @SarahXP - The result of `NotesUIWorkspace.PickListStrings` is a variant containing a list of strings when the user presses "OK", so since you only allow selecting a single value, you can access it with `picklist(0)`. However, note that this would generate an error if the user has pressed "Cancel", in which case the dialog returns an `EMPTY` variant. To account for this case, do `If IsEmpty(picklist) Then Exit Sub`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use Dialog list field with @DbColumn formula, as choices (second tab of field properties):

```
@DbColumn( class : cache ; server : database ; view ; columnNumber )
```

Example:

```
@DbColumn( "ReCache"; ""; "x_asean_search"; 4 )
```

will return all values from the fourth column of the "x_asean_search" view of the current database.

Details here:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_DBCOLUMN_NOTES_DATABASES.html

Comment: thx Hristo & mbonaci... I've wrked out with the pickliststrings and i've got wat i've wanted... i.e to display a list of superior1 keywords to select. I've used the foll script :

Comment: Well... I've got the solution for getting the selected keyword to the field "Superior1"... can anyone help me with this... I wanna compare a combination of 2 fields "Office" & "Fields" with a column "OfficeGroup" of the view...for eg: Field A value & Field B value with Column "AB"... hw do i concatenate both the fields..? I prefer LOTUS SCRIPT instead of formula for this plz... thx...